# Industries which maintain their own versions of common data?

Tags: finance, ontology

We have a product for the Australian mortgage brokers which is a centralised database of all lender/bank loan products. We do this because every large broker group must update their own version of the loan product data because the banks/lenders are too lazy to provide their loan product data in a common format like XML/JSON/etc. The banks feel that just having the information on their websites is support enough for the broker groups which is wrong and crazy.

So our product allows the broker groups to all maintain/update the same data repository which makes mistakes or omissions far less possible.

Does anyone know of other industries which also have the same inefficiencies and would benefit from a centralised data repository?

Answer (score 1):

Many industries.

The word missing from your question is "[Ontology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_(information_science))", and in particular "Industrial Ontology", or even more specific "Financial Industry Business Ontology". I think with that vocabulary, you can find some good results about how other industries organize data between companies. Whether or not you keep a central data repository, the data is structured and standardized.

---

**schema.org** organizes this kind of activity

> Schema.org is a collaborative, community activity with a mission to create, maintain, and promote schemas for structured data on the Internet, on web pages, in email messages, and beyond.

You can find further information in your industry, although with schema.org you'll find many other use cases.

https://schema.org/docs/financial.html

https://schema.org/FinancialProduct

https://schema.org/LoanOrCredit

https://schema.org/MortgageLoan

Comment: the non-profit schema.org - that is run by the big three search engines

Comment: good point. I edited it out